# Cant answer Highly active question even with enough rep

Tags: support, questions, answers, answering-questions

I am trying to answer this question:

[Where can find older versions of Apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14910/where-can-find-older-versions)

but it says this:

> Highly active question. Earn 10 reputation (not counting the association
> bonus) in order to answer this question.

I am confused, as I have earned that:

| points | link |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | https://android.stackexchange.com/a/242870 |
| 5 | [Cold boot: snapshot failed to load](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242222) |
| 5 | [Magisk v23 with Android Studio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242246) |

Comment: As the duplicate mentions, this is a known quirk that putting a bounty means *reducing the earned reputation*, thus users with association bonus might be put into negative earn and must regain it back and have above 110 rep to be able to post on protected questions. Visit the duplicate for more info.

Comment: That said, I've unprotected the question, so feel free to post your answer!